# Initial styling of <sup> and <sub> tags

Tags: html, css

So I've recently realized that a lot (basically all) html tags that reside in the body are basically text tags with some styling:

e.g

```
a {
    color: blue; /*of some sort*/
    text-decoration: underline;
}

b {
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

So I was curious. For the <sup> and <sub> tags, I was wondering, how can I shift text upwards inline? It would be interesting to do something where you have wavy text. So in another way of saying this, what is the *initial* styling of the <sup> and <sub> tags?

**Edit:** It would also be nice for me to be able to play with these

Comment: Curiously, the HTML5 spec says that [sup and sub are expected to have `line-height:normal`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#phrasing-content-3) in their default styling, yet I can't find any browser that does so.

Comment: @Alohci Does that mean that browsers tell you the default styling for each tag?

Comment: Yes, the information can be obtained from the developer tools (F12), although the details of how vary a bit between the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the default style for the `sup` tag:

```
sup {
    font-size: smaller;
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

```css
.sup {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<p>E = mc<sup>2</sup> - or does it?</p>
<p>E = mc<span class="sup">2</span> - or does it?</p>
```

Here is the default style for the `sub` tag:

```
sup {
    font-size: smaller;
    vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```css
.sub {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
```

```html
<p>E = mc<sub>2</sub> - or does it?</p>
<p>E = mc<span class="sub">2</span> - or does it?</p>
```

So yup, that means we can do this:

```css
.a {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: sub;
}
.b {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
.c {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.d {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
.e {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<p>Yay! 
    <span class="a">u</span>
    <span class="b">n</span>
    <span class="c">i</span>
    <span class="d">c</span>
    <span class="e">o</span>
    <span class="d">r</span>
    <span class="e">n</span>
    <span class="c">s</span>
</p>
```

If you ever wanted to use numerical values for the vertical-align, those would work as well, like this:

```css
.a {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 0px;
}
.b {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}
.c {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: -4px;
}
.d {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: -2px;
}
.e {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 0px;
}
.f {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 2px;
}
.g {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 4px;
}
.h {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 2px;
}
.i {
  font-size: smaller;
  vertical-align: 0px;
}
```

```html
<p>Yay! 
    <span class="a">r</span>
    <span class="b">a</span>
    <span class="c">i</span>
    <span class="d">n</span>
    <span class="e">b</span>
    <span class="f">o</span>
    <span class="g">w</span>
    <span class="h">s</span>
    <span class="i">a</span>
    <span class="h">n</span>
    <span class="g">d</span>
    <span class="f">u</span>
    <span class="e">n</span>
    <span class="d">i</span>
    <span class="c">c</span>
    <span class="b">o</span>
    <span class="a">r</span>
    <span class="b">n</span>
    <span class="c">s</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks this was very useful, it allowed me to shift them to my ability. Is it possible to have a numerical vertical align?

Comment: why use `span` with the default values from `sup` & `sub` when you simply have those tag? By using the corrects tags it will be better semantically

Comment: yes, that was a demonstration - just showing it works!

Answer (score 2):

The default styles for both tags are the following:

```
small, sub, sup { font-size: .83em }
sub             { vertical-align: sub }
sup             { vertical-align: super }
```

You can see more info [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)

---

> Edit: It would also be nice for me to be able to play with these

Just use the tags.

```html
<div>
  <sup>1</sup>
  <sub>2</sub>
  <sup>3</sup>
  <sub>4</sub>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <sup>a</sup>
  <sub>b</sub>
  <sup>c</sup>
  <sub>d</sub>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the real answer is *it depends* each and every browser can implement their own style on each and every element.

That is also why most recent websites use reset and normalize CSS sheets.

For example, in the [normalize.css project](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), the styles are:

```css
sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}
```

<sup>*Source: https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/fc091cce1534909334c1911709a39c22d406977b/normalize.css#L125*</sup>

Comment: That's not the default styles

Comment: @dippas totally agree. But standards are meant to be broken, bugs happen, etc. If that was not the case, there wouldn't be so much complains about *"why is this or that not rendering properly in this browser when it works in that other one"*